# How to call controller function inside blade php?

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to figure out how to call function from controller.

When I call this in blade php its working fine

```
Todo::where('is_done', false)->count();
```

But Im trying to make less mess in blade php and call it like

```
{{ Todo::isDone(); }}
```

What im trying in controller is

```
public static function isDone() 
{
    return Todo::where('is_done', false)->count();
    
}
```

Getting error

> Call to undefined method App\Models\Todo::isDone()

Comment: why don't you make that a method on your Model?

Comment: Well... Now its working when I did this in Model. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could put it on the model or just use the full namespace. Try

```
 {{ App\Http\Controllers\Todo::isDone() }}
```